# Can't access kubernetes cluster with Istio gateway

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have a k8s cluster with Istio ingress.
I deployed a deployment, service, gateway and a virtual service but I still can't access my service from outside the cluster.
I'm able to access my service by accessing the workers on the nodePort specified, but I'd expect that the Istio gateway will still listen on port 80 on my master but it doesn't look like that.
What am I doing wrong here?

service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: microservices-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: microservices-deployment
  ports:
    - port: 5001
      targetPort: 5001
      nodePort: 30007
```

deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: microservices-deployment
  labels:
    app: microservices-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      name: microservices-deployment
      labels:
        app: microservices-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: microservices-deployment
          image: *** private docker registry ***
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5001
      restartPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: microservices-deployment
```

ingress.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: microservices-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: microservices
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - microservices-gateway
  http:
    - match:
      route:
      - destination:
          host: *** master hostname ***
          port:
            number: 5001
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I checked your configuration and everything looks set up correctly. There is only one little mistake to fix is your [virtual service](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/).

Change it from

```
http:
    - match:
      route:
      - destination:
          host: *** master hostname ***
          port:
            number: 5001
```

to

```
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: microservices-service
        port:
          number: 5001
```

And you should be able to access it with your istio gateway external-ip LoadBalancer/NodePort.
More about it [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/#determining-the-ingress-ip-and-ports).

```
kubectl get svc -n istio-system | grep istio-ingress
```

---

Quick example with nginx, note that I'm using LoadBalancer instead of NodePort.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: nginx1
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx1
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello nginx1 > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html"]

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: frontend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: frontend

---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: nginx-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"

---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nginx-virtual
spec:
  gateways:
  - nginx-gateway
  hosts:
  - "*"
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
```

---

```
kubectl get svc -n istio-system | grep ingress
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   xx.x.xx.xxx   xx.xx.xx.xx  15021:30880/TCP,80:31983/TCP,443:31510/TCP,15443:32267/TCP   2d2h
```

Test with curl

```
curl -v xx.xx.xx.xx/
GET / HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Hello nginx1
```

Comment: I will check it out today. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Yaakov Shami Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted or up vote it.

Comment: I don't have a Load Balancer so I'm using a NodePort, but I can't even access my gateaway. I'm getting an IP and a port but they are not accessible from within the server and outside of it. What can be wrong?

Comment: What is your infrastructure? Have you changed the istio ingress gateway type from LoadBalancer to NodePort as mentioned [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/23877#issuecomment-674592721)?

Comment: I'm not able to change the type for some reason.. I don't even have istioctl